# Pushing data to Hive from SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive

I am using a SqlServer database and need to connect to a Hive database. The end goal is to be able to push data from SqlServer to a Hive table. Connecting to SqlServer from Hive via Sqoop is not an option. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

How big is the data ? If your database contains few tables than you can export the sqlserver db to excel or csv and load them into hive else you can write some code to accompolish this.

Comment: Very large (few hundred GB), we want to set up a framework that exports data to Hive without having to export to CSV files first.